# Fiddler encodes decoded response. How can I do the same in vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpwebrequest, decode, fiddler

I am using httpwebrequest to get a response from a website. In this response I should see an xml. But in my response it just shows me jibberish. I used fiddler to see what I get. I get an encoded response, which I manually need to decode to see the contents(this is in fiddler).

How can I do the same thing in vb.net ?

**edit** The response comes back as **https**.

I have tried:

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myResult,myStreamwriter)

  Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("www.url.com/$filetype=xml"), HttpWebRequest)

        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        request.ContentType = "text/xml, charset=utf-8"
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate,sdch")
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4")
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3")

        Using getResponse = request.GetResponse
            Dim webServiceResponse = getResponse.GetResponseStream()

   Dim xmlreader As New IO.StreamReader(webServiceResponse)

'here is where it shows a really gibberish output
     Dim myResult As String = xmlreader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: What do you mean with decode? Gzip decompression? Byte to String decoding?

Comment: I just checked now and it says Content-encoding: gzip. So I believe gzip Decompression. Though I thought this was because of my https connection to the website.

Comment: Could you supply some code how you make your http web request?

Comment: Sure, one sec need some time to make it readable

Comment: So connecting to a https connection is exactly the same as http? Since I see no one mentioning that. I have no idea what to do, since know one is mentioning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to decompress the response.

Have you tried HttpWebRequest AutomaticDecompression? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx

```
httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Comment: Looking at the edit to your question.  Setting automatic decompression will also add the Accept Encoding behavior.  I'm guessing you don't want to include sdch?  It's difficult to decode and I was under the impression that very few things support it right now (just google?)

Comment: I will try, but I just checked. There is also an txt version of the same page and information. When I look into the header it does NOT say that "**Content-encoding: gzip**" but still gives me the same gibberish response. And when I use the "decode" button on fiddler, it shows me the right result.

Comment: Actually I can remove it, I actually just did that because I didn't want to rule anything out. And later when it works I would slim my code down and see if it would work without for example "sdch"

Comment: This has been the answer. As the first comment stated, I too thought that the gzip would have been done when "acceptEncoding" is set to gzip in the header, but thats **WRONG**. Mabye if you have an explanation for the reason it being different? I'd appreciate it, since I spent so much time on it I would like to know.

Comment: Setting the Accept Encoding header in the request lets the server know that we can handle the said encodings.  It doesn't actually do anything on the client end towards actually handling the decoding.  On a less functional api you have to manually check for the Content Encoding header on the response to know how to decode.